# Install Laravel Socialite without composer?

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I was adding social authentication using laravel socialte. and It works prfectly on local machine. but when I add that functionality to live server and putting the package inside composer directory and updating composer.json is not working. I am asking if there is any possible way to install the package to a web server without composer?

Comment: Why don't you run `composer install` locally and then upload the `vendor` directory?

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work that way.

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work that way"?